# UK visa bank statement info

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

I need some info please. I am going to apply for a UK visa for PLAB exam. About the bank account statement, I have a joint account with my brother in an Indian bank, but I am currently not in India. The card is with me and is named after my brother and the statement mentions my name along with my brother's. The card is being used by me for the past 6 months as required. Is this acceptable or will there be some problem regarding this? Anybody with some experience with this?

Comment: @DJClayworth off-topic really? He's asking about the requirement for bank statements to get a short-term visa and has a complicated situation (a shared account). Why is that more appropriate for money.SE or Expats.SE? (hint: I don't think it is)

Comment: Do you have payslips to corroborate the deposits in the bank account ? Card doesn't matter but the deposits of your salary will help.

Comment: PLAB exams are within the visitor programme and the person needs everything the generic tourist needs.  As long as the question is about the visa and not about the test, it's fine IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

They do not care about the card.  If your joint bank account *is not* at one of the [unacceptable banks in India](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/370997/20141106_immigration_rules_appendix_p_final.pdf), the statements will be acceptable.  There are about 300+ banks on the list so you'll need to check carefully.  If your bank *is* on the list then your statements will not be used as evidence.

However, because it's a joint account you will need to include evidence on the provenance of the funds.  Incoming deposits clearly sourced to you will be the highest quality of evidence.  Failing that, you will need to include something that shows the funds are actually yours for use during your visit.